# Improper behavior of split function

Tags: vb.net, windows

Code:

```
 Dim list1 As New List(Of String)(line_items.Split("<<>>"))
```

I am trying to split following string.

```
line_items=8903385828097<>PRINTED  TWILL DUNGAREES<>1<>25.94<>50.00<>497.50<>524.86<>995.00<<>>
```

Getting wrong information. Please refer to output:

[image: check output here.]

Answer (score 3):

The `Split` method takes a parameter of type `Char`. Your code won't compile with "Option Strict On" because you have passed a parameter of type `String`. When Option Strict is off, the compiler makes an implicit typecast from `String` to `Char` and therefore "<"c (the first character) is passed rather than "<<>>".

If you want to split by the string "<>" or "<<>>", you will have to pass one of these values as the sole element of a string array.

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of String)(line_items.Split(New String() {"<>"}, StringSplitOptions.None))

Dim list1 As New List(Of String)(line_items.Split(New String() {"<<>>"}, StringSplitOptions.None))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of String)(line_items.Replace("<<>>", "").Replace("<>", "#").Split("#"))
```

Comment: Sir, I know i can use replace function to replace <<>> with some single character and <> with other single char, but why is split function is behaving like this?

Comment: I understood you were looking for a solution to solve your problem

Comment: Using this approach will work (with Option Strict Off) because the multi-character string by which you are trying to split is reduced to a single character which is able to be typecast to a Char without any truncation. My strong recommendation is to always code with Option Strict On and not to rely on implicit typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code:

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of String)(line_items.Split(New String() {"<<>>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

I was using `New Char()` instead of `New String()`. `New String()` worked well.